# biblatex cite current frame in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

Is it possible to cite only the reference in current slide (frame) of beamer in a bibliography at the bottom of this slide?

I tried this one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex8,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=none,
  firstinits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  uniquelist=false,
  refsegment=section,
  citestyle=numeric
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mini.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Start}
\begin{frame}
  first cite\cite{Julie2006}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\section{2nd}
\begin{frame}
  Second cite\cite{gyof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with the mini.bib as:

```
@article{gyof,
  Author={BLJ},
  Journal={joural1},
  volume={15},
  pages={1337},
  Year={1985}
}
@article{Julie2006,
  Author={JBS},
  Journal={journal2},
  volume={74},
  pages={144411},
  Year={2006}
}
```

[image: this] is what I am getting...I have tried `refsegment=section` as have not found anything with frame.

Comment: `\footfullcite`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the biblatex `refsection` option is not compatible with `beamer`. There are a few workarounds. The first is to manually insert `\newrefsection` commands at the appropriate places, the second is to use `etoolbox` facilities to automatise this; namely you need to add the following line:

```
\preto{\section}{\newrefsection}
```

[image]